# ¿Añadir texto al inicio y al final de cada linea de un parrafo? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bien, el problema que me han planteado se basa en lo siguiente:

tengo tres campos de texto, en los primeros dos debo ingresar una palabra o una frase corta y luego en el tercero debo crear un párrafo, posteriormente con el botón de unir, los tres campos deben unirse y los datos de los primeros dos campos deben de aparecer al inicio y al final de cada linea del tercer texto, les dejo un ejemplo gráfico para que se entienda mejor mi idea.

Todo lo que está escrito el rojo lo hice a base de paint.
(la linea azul es imaginaria solo para marcar espacio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional a la imagen dejo este código que es un ejemplo similar, pero no es capaz de diferenciar los saltos de linea para luego agregar el primero y el segundo dato.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form name="prueba">
   Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA"; />
   Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB"; />
<br><br>
   Contenido Medio
<br>
   <textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="50" rows="10">
   </textarea>
<br>
</form>
<script>
function unirTexto(){

var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var resultado= document.getElementById('resultado');
resultado.innerHTML = c1+t1+c2;

}

function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value = "";
document.getElementById('textB').value = "";
document.getElementById('textC').value = "";
resultado.innerHTML = " ";
}
</script>
<button onclick="unirTexto()" id="Boton">Unir</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button> <br>
Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías tomar tomar el valor del `textarea` y luego separarlos con expresiones regulares por los salto de línea con `t1.split(/\n/g)` para luego recorrerlo en un `for ()`, por ejemplo:

```js
function unirTexto(){

  var c1 = document.getElementById('textA').value;
  var c2 = document.getElementById('textB').value;
  var t1 = document.getElementById('textC').value;
  
  // parrafos
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  // string para ingresar en el html
  var html = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    html += c1 + p[i] + c2 + "<br>";
  }
  
  // agrego el texto al DOM
  resultado.innerHTML = html;
}

function limpiar() {
  document.getElementById('textA').value = "";
  document.getElementById('textB').value = "";
  document.getElementById('textC').value = "";
  resultado.innerHTML = " ";
}
```

```html
<form name="prueba">
   Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA"; />
   Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB"; />
<br><br>
   Contenido Medio
<br>
   <textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
</form>
<button onclick="unirTexto()" id="Boton">Unir</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button> <br>
Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
<br>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es eso lo que buscaba